# DTO inheritance in Nest js ony includes properties from parent class

Tags: nestjs

I'm tryng to create a DTO Class responsible for parsing paginated query filters.

So I created this class:

```js
    import { Transform } from 'class-transformer';
    import { IsNumber, IsOptional, IsEnum, Min } from 'class-validator';
    import { SortOrder } from '../enums/SortOrder';
    import { toNumber } from '../helpers/toNumber';
    
    export class GenericFilter {
      @Transform(({ value }) => toNumber(value, { default: 1 }))
      @IsNumber({}, { message: ' "page" atrribute should be a number' })
      @Min(1)
      public page?: number = 1;
    
      @Transform(({ value }) => toNumber(value, { default: 50 }))
      @Min(1)
      @IsNumber({}, { message: ' "pageSize" attribute should be a number ' })
      public pageSize?: number = 50;
    
      @IsOptional()
      public orderBy?: string;
    
      @IsEnum(SortOrder)
      @IsOptional()
      public sortOrder?: SortOrder = SortOrder.DESC;
    }
```

Then I try to extend this class from other DTO for specific cases of filtering, like this:

```js
    import { IsDateString, IsNumber, IsOptional } from 'class-validator';
    import { GenericFilter } from 'src/common/interfaces/GenericFilter';
    
    export class OperationLogFilterDto extends GenericFilter {
      @IsDateString()
      @IsOptional()
      public dateFrom?: Date;
    
      @IsDateString()
      @IsOptional()
      public dateTo?: Date;
    
      @IsNumber()
      @IsOptional()
      public userId?: number;
    }
```

And use it like this:

```js
    import { Controller, Get, Query } from '@nestjs/common';
    import { OperationLogFilterDto } from './dto/OperationLogFilter.dto';
    import { AuditService } from './audit.service';
    
    @Controller('audit')
    export class AuditController {
      constructor(private service: AuditService) {}
    
      @Get('/operation-logs')
      getAllOperationLogs(@Query() filters: OperationLogFilterDto) {
        console.log(filters);
        return this.service.getOperationLogs(filters);
      }
    }
```

The problem is that the console log shows only the properties from the Parent class, and ignores any other filters I send that are included in `OperationLogFilterDto`

IE:

[image: request query]

[image: console log result]

How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I just had a typo on the request I was using to test..